# Pass a particular state in one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, expo

I am working on an app that requires the user to take a picture, I have been able to work around a camera component, however I am lost as to how to pass the image taken to another component screen where the camera component has been imported. 
Below are the camera component and where I want to pass the new state of the camera component.

I haven't tried anything concrete really, because I dont know if i should be passing state or props.

Camera Component

```
      import React from 'react';
      import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image, Alert, Modal, } from 'react-native';
      import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';
      import { Entypo, Ionicons, MaterialIcons, } from '@expo/vector-icons';


      export default class Camera extends React.Component {
        state = {
          hasCameraPermission: null,
          type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
        };

        async componentDidMount() {
          const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
          this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
        }

        takePicture = async () => {
          if (this.camera) {
            const photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({ base64: true });

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', photo.base64);
            formData.append('type', 'base64');

            this.setState({
              latestImage: photo.uri,
              isCameraVisible: false
            });
        }
        };

        openCamera = () => {
          const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
          if (!hasCameraPermission) {
            Alert.alert('Error', 'No access to camera');
          } else {
            this.setState({ isCameraVisible: true });
          }
        };

        closeCamera = () => {
          this.setState({
            isCameraVisible: false
          });
        };

                render() {
                  const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;

                  if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
                  return <View />;
                  } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
                    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <View style={styles.container}>
                        {!this.state.isCameraVisible && (
                            <View style={styles.mainContent}>
                              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openCamera}>
                                  <MaterialIcons name="camera-alt" size={40} color="#1083bb" />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                              </View>
                              {this.state.latestImage && (
                                <Image
                                  style={styles.latestImage}
                                  resizeMode='cover'
                                  source={{ uri: this.state.latestImage }}
                                />
                              )}
                            </View>
                        )}

                        {this.state.isCameraVisible && (
                          <Modal
                            transparent
                            animationType={'slide'}
                            visible={this.state.ModalVisibleStatus}
                          >
                              <View
                              style={{
                                flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFF'
                              }}
                              >
                          <Camera
                            style={styles.camera}
                            type={this.state.type}
                            ref={ref => {
                              this.camera = ref;
                            }}
                          >
                  <View style={styles.cameraContent}>
                    <View
                      style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                      }}
                    >
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.buttonCamera}
                        onPress={this.takePicture}
                      >
                        <Entypo name="circle" size={50} color="#FFFFFF" />
                      </TouchableOpacity>

                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.buttonCloseCamera}
                        onPress={this.closeCamera}
                      >
                        <MaterialIcons name="close" size={25} color="#FFFFFF" />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    </View>
                </Camera>
                </View>
                </Modal>
              )}
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
      }
      });
```

Index Component where I want to preview the image taken

```
      import React, { Component } from 'react';
      import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity,
      Modal, Button, KeyboardAvoidingView, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
      import { Block, Input } from '../../components';
      import { theme } from '../../constants';
      import Camera from './upload';


      class Details extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            receiverName: '',
            receiverPhone: '',
            ModalVisibleStatus: false,

          };
        }

      ShowModalFunction(visible) {
        this.setState({
          ModalVisibleStatus: visible
        });
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }

      handleChangeName = (receiverName) => {
        this.setState({
          receiverName
        });
      }

      handleChangePhone = (receiverPhone) => {
        this.setState({
          receiverPhone
        });
      }


        render() {
          return (
            <View
            style={styles.Container}
            >
                  <Input
                    placeholder="Inputs"
                    phone
                    autoCorrect
                    style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={this.handleChangePhone}
                    defaultValue={this.state.receiverPhone}
                    onFocus={() => {
                      this.ShowModalFunction(true);
                      Keyboard.dismiss();
                     }}
                     autoFocus={false}
                  />
              <View
                style={styles.content}
              >
                <View
                  style={{ flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row' }}
                >

                      <Modal
                        transparent
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        visible={this.state.ModalVisibleStatus}
                      >
                          <View
                          style={{
                            flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFF'
                          }}
                          >
                          <View style={styles.navBar}>
                            <Text style={styles.navBarHeader}>Delivery Information</Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                              onPress={() => {
                                this.ShowModalFunction(!this.state.ModalVisibleStatus);
                                Keyboard.dismiss();
                              }}
                            >
                              <Text style={styles.navBarButton}>Done</Text>
                              </TouchableOpacity>
                              </View>
                          <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.login} behavior="padding">
                            <Block padding={[0, theme.sizes.base * 2]}>
                              <Block style={{ paddingVertical: 30 }}>
                                <Input
                                  label="Receiver's Name"
                                  text
                                  style={styles.input}
                                  onChangeText={this.handleChangeName}
                                  defaultValue={this.state.receiverName}
                                />
                                <Input
                                  label="Receiver's Phone no."
                                  phone
                                  style={styles.input}
                                  onChangeText={this.handleChangePhone}
                                  defaultValue={this.state.receiverPhone}
                                />
                                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

                                <Camera
                                />
                                </View>
                              </Block>
                            </Block>
                          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                      </View>
                    </Modal>

                  <Block style={{ flex: 1, paddingRight: 100, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
                    <View>{Where I want to preview the image}</View>
                  </Block>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }
      }


      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        input: {
          borderRadius: 0,
          borderWidth: 0,
          paddingTop: 0,
          borderBottomColor: theme.colors.gray2,
          borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        },

        TextStyle: {
          fontSize: 20,
          marginBottom: 20,
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          padding: 20,
          textAlign: 'center'
        },
        navBar: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingTop: 35,
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#34495E'
      },
        navBarButton: {
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          textAlign: 'center',
          width: 64
        },
        navBarHeader: {
          flex: 1,
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          textAlign: 'center',
          fontSize: 16,
        },
      });

      export default Focal;
```

I am hoping to preview the picture taken upon the click of the done button on the View tag as described

Comment: If you're storing the image in state, why not simply pass the state on (or just the entries that you need) as a prop?

Comment: can you kindly explain how I can achieve this please, I have tried hacky ways I know, but clearly they dint work. would really appreciate if you can direct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function in index that takes the image as argument and setState it, and send this function to where you take the photo as a prop then use it when you take the photo.

in Details class:

```js
// add this
handleNewPhoto = img => {
  this.setState({ image: img });
}

//and this
<Camera handleNewPhoto={this.handleNewPhoto} />
```

and in Camera class:

```js
takePicture = async () => {
          if (this.camera) {
            const photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({ base64: true });

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', photo.base64);
            formData.append('type', 'base64');

            this.setState({
              latestImage: photo.uri,
              isCameraVisible: false
            });
            this.props.handleNewPhoto(photo.uri); // <---- add this
        }
        };
```

Edit: you might also have to add this to the details class constructor

```js
constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            receiverName: '',
            receiverPhone: '',
            ModalVisibleStatus: false,

          };
   this.handleNewPhoto = this.handleNewPhoto.bind(this); // <---- this
        }
```

Edit2:

to show the image add inside the view:

```js
{this.state.image ? 
  <Image
      style={{width: width, height: height}}
      source={{uri: this.state.image}}
  /> : null 
}
```

Comment: How do I pass or preview it then in the bottom View tag in Detail class?

Comment: As you can see, I rendered the camera component in the modal tag along with the text input, I want to preview it inside “<View>{where I want to preview the image}<\View>onPress of the done text button

Comment: Than you so much man, you just saved me.
I am new to react native, I would really be glad to have someone show me the ropes while going through the learning process

Comment: you're welcome bro, I'm glad to help.
if you have an issue that you couldn't find an answer for here add me on twitter @linkinmedo and I'll help you if I can.

Comment: You have been very kind, however I am not on twitter, I was hoping I could get your email, or maybe facebook

Comment: You can find me on facebook with the same name here, add me there.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do so
 1. If you are moving to Details.js using react-navigation then just pass the state in params like : 
    `this.props.navigation.navigate('details',{data:this.state})
2. If you are rendering the detail component inside your camera component, then you can do so like

```
<Deails {...this.props} {...this.state} />
```

And access this in Details.js like this:

```
<Image source={{uri:this.props.latestImage}} />
```

Comment: I think you missed some code at #2, please edit it accordingly.